# How can I embed Weblogic server in java?

Tags: java, weblogic, embed

I am searching any way for embedding Weblogic server in Java , I know its possible because we have maven plugins for Weblogic which embeds Weblogic in maven, But googling for it did'nt gave me useful output, Does anybody know how can we embed wemlogic in java program ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebLogic doesn't provide an embedded API so, even if it's a pure Java Server and if you can thus call `weblogic.Server` from Java code, you will have to handle everything yourself (starting the container, waiting until it's started, deploying things, waiting until they are deployed, etc). In other words, this will require some work. 
Maybe have a look at the sources of [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/), although Cargo isn't really starting an embedded Weblogic (i.e. running `weblogic.Server` in the same JVM). This will give you an idea of what has to be done. Or, depending on your needs, use [Cargo Java API](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Functional+testing).

But if you need a full Java EE server and if this is an option, I would use GlassFish v3 in embedded mode instead of WebLogic, it will be much simpler. Check the following links and see yourself:

- [Embedding Glassfish V3 in Unit Test - Two Jars, Three Lines Of Code And Five Seconds Start With Deployment](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_glassfish_v3_in_unit)
- [Embedding EJB 3.1 Container Into Your Unit Tests - Boot Time: 5 Seconds](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_ejb_3_1_container)
- [Using the EJBContainer API with or without Maven (but with GlassFish v3)](http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/testing_ejb_3_1_s)
- [TOTD #128: EJBContainer.createEJBContainer: Embedded EJB using GlassFish v3](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_128_ejbcontainer_createejbcontainer_embedded)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need WLS specifically, of any servlet container would do? If the latter is OK, then use Jetty.

WLS is not designed to be embeddable. But you can do it. After all, WLS is just a class named weblogic.Server. Setup classpath correctly, setup PATH and other environment variables (see setDomainEnv.sh and startWeblogic.sh), start that class from Java, and you have an "embedded" WLS.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way, but I don't know it. My experience from writing maven plugins tells me that the most likely way that the plugin works is that it starts up a new command line process just like you would normally start up the server. So in a sense, not really embedded it.

The best way to see is to track down the source of the plugin and see how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic doesn't support embedded mode like Glassfish but you can have control over your Weblogic using "WebLogic Maven Plugin", this provide several maven goals for managing and working with Weblogic instance.

See [this](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/12/installing-and-using-new-weblogic-12.html) link for further information.